# Why does the QR Scanner Ionic plugin generate an error?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**EDIT**: I managed to make the plugin work, but when I test the app on my iPhone and click the button, Xcode sends me a warning: `THREAD WARNING: ['QRScanner'] took '468.501953' ms. Plugin should use a background thread`.

---

I tried so many things and follow so many articles and tutorials (also here, on SO) to get rid of this. I'm building an Ionic app, using the [QR Scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/) plugin that this framework provides. My `app.module.ts` is:

```
// Here are the basic Ionic import statements.
// Eventually, I import the plugin to scan QR codes.
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp, HomePage ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp) ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ MyApp, HomePage ],
  providers: [ StatusBar, SplashScreen, QRScanner,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

The folder structure is:

[image]

My app has only one page, `HomePage`, and the content of the `src/pages/home/home.ts` file is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private qrScanner: QRScanner) { }  
  scanQrCode() {
    this.qrScanner.prepare().then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
      if (status.authorized) {
        let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {             console.log('Scanned something', text); 
          this.qrScanner.hide();
          scanSub.unsubscribe();
        });
      } else if (status.denied) {
        // ...
      } else {
        // ...
      }
    }).catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
  }
}
```

Inside the `src/pages/home/home.html` file, I have:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="scanQrCode()"></button>
</ion-content>
```

I build the app and run it on my iPhone 5, but when I click the button to scan a code, Xcode sends this: `Error is [Object object]`. Do you know why?

Comment: i cannot see there you put the content into your scan (from camera or pretaken pix or ?). But maybe start with a better output of the error - JSON.stringify(e)

Comment: Using the iOS simulator of Xcode and `JSON.stringify(e)`, the error is: `Error is {"name":"FRONT_CAMERA_UNAVAILABLE","code":4,"_message":"The front camera is unavailable."}`. However, running the app in the iPhone, the error becomes a warning: `THREAD WARNING: ['QRScanner'] took '711.019043' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.` In both cases, the camera doesn't open.

Comment: And you have given permission to use the camara ?

Comment: @split yes, of course.

Comment: I also found this https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/121

Comment: You seems to have a point. Can you try it on a Android ?

Comment: You have seen the recomendation on https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner : _"If you run into issues in your own project, try the test project in this repo to confirm your environment is set up properly: npm run gen-tests && npm run test:ios."_

Comment: @split same on Android, it doesn't open the camera.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178513/discussion-between-franco-scarpa-and-split).